# Tycho build is failing because of p2 repositories

Tags: tycho, p2

I use Tycho already a couple of months now. But yesterday I got an issue during building my application with Tycho. On first look, it was a repository that was down. But today I have the same issue and not only on the general Eclipse 4.7 repo but on other repo's.

I use those repositories in my target file:

```
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7/" />
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen" />
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nattable/releases/1.5.0/repository/"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nebula/snapshot/"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nebula/incubation/snapshot/"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nattable/snapshots/latest/repository/"/>
```

The error that I'm getting when I build it on my dev and on my build server is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition D:\Jenkins\workspace\Client Staging\neon\neon.target: Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7/: Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7. HTTP Server 'Bad Gateway' : http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7/R-4.7.3a-201803300640/content.xml.xz: HttpComponents connection error response code 502. -> [Help 1]
```

Does someone know how to fix this? I need this to build my application on an automatic way and deploy the application on different locations.

The full Maven errors looks like:

```
org.apache.maven.MavenExecutionException: Failed to resolve target definition C:\Users\test\Downloads\test\neon\neon.target: Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7/
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:100)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:267)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared.BuildFailureException: Failed to resolve target definition C:\Users\test\Downloads\test\neon\neon.target: Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7/
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContent(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolverService.resolveFromArguments(TargetDefinitionResolverService.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolverService.getTargetDefinitionContent(TargetDefinitionResolverService.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.resolveTargetDefinitions(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.manager.ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(P2DependencyResolver.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.facade.TargetDefinitionResolutionException: Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7/
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver$LoadedIULocation.loadRepository(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver$LoadedIULocation.<init>(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver$ResolverRun.addLocation(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContentWithExceptions(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContent(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:94)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.addChild(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.<init>(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver$LoadedIULocation.loadRepository(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:288)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: HTTP Server 'Bad Gateway' : http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7/R-4.7-201706120950/content.xml.xz
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.updateCache(CacheManager.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCacheFromFile(CacheManager.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteRepositoryCacheManager.createCacheFromFile(RemoteRepositoryCacheManager.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:78)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.addChild(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:166)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransferException: HttpComponents connection error response code 502.
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:667)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:885)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.readInto(FileReader.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:101)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.updateCache(CacheManager.java:402)
        ... 48 more
```

Comment: we have the same problem since last Friday, I am ruling out proxy as the same happens outside of company network.

Comment: Ok then my first thought can be correct. I think the p2 repositories are failing because sometime I got some strange errors when browsing the them.

Comment: looks like today our builds are able to be built, situation is more stable than in last days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an unstable p2 repository. Didn't changed anything and today it's working just fine.